# Не понимаю JSP и HTML

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, jsp

Здравствуйте, умею верстать сайты (средней сложности). Сейчас учусь писать веб-приложения на java, параллельно изучаю spring. Все хорошо, но я не понимаю, как это происходит в жизни.

Допустим сверстали мы по макету, получили html, css и js файлы. Там мы употребляли `form`, отправляли на сервлет, всё понятно. Но мы можем работать только с jsp? Как туда прикручивается дизайн который мы сверстали? То есть, мы просто копируем наш htm и переделываем под jsp, подключая уже туда наши css и js?

Я думаю это как-то красивее делается. Например после авторизации у нас показывается всегда под каким логином мы находимся. Где это делается? В каком месте мы производим эту вставку значения login.

Извините если непонятно совсем описал.

Comment: Вы можете сформулировать вопрос как-то поконкретнее?

Comment: Думайте о JSP, как о шаблонизаторе. Если надо показать имя пользователя после  входа, значит нужно из сервлета в JSP передать объект, содержащий имя пользователя и флаг входа, а в JSP при наличии флага выводить имя пользователя. Можно и без сервлета, тогда код придется писать в самом JSP, а это нехорошо. Ну и в целом: кому нужен JSP в 2017м году? )

Comment: @Nofate я как то не понял - что значит кому нужны сервлеты в 2017 году? Я конечно давно уже не писал сервлеты, но позвольте полюбопытствовать что там происходит то в Java web разработке?

Comment: @Barmaley, опечатка, не "сервлеты", а "JSP". Впрочем и сервлеты под большимм вопросом, как и весь EE. Теперь в вебной джаве балом правит Spring Boot/Dropwizard, а то и микровебфреймворки, шаблонизаторы по вкусу (тот же Thymeleaf) и Angular/React на фронтенде. Под капотом оно еще есть, но скоро вырастет поколение, не писавшее сервлетов руками )

Answer (score 0):

Касательно регистрации 
https://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/ вот много примеров как реализовать.

http://javastudy.ru/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc/  вот еще неплохое место где можно получить ответы на ваши вопросы.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка. **Однако вы можете перенести текст ответа в комментарии к вопросу**.